# Can I query Grok's ZODB instance outside the web application scope?

Tags: python, zope, zodb, grok

I have a grok-based webapp that persists data using ZODB. Can I query the object db offline i.e. from a python script that would be run on the webserver hosting the grok/paste webapp instance?

And would there be any issues in doing so while the web server is interacting with the database simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the ZODB with python and inspect the data, yes. To do so while you also run the web site, you'll need to use a concurrency layer like [ZEO](http://www.zodb.org/documentation/guide/zeo.html) or [RelStorage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RelStorage); plain FileStorage does not support concurrent access otherwise.